# Quick writing to log file after http request

Tags: php, python, performance, logging

I currently finished building a Web server who's main responsibility is to simply take the contents of the body data in each http post request and write it to a log file. The contents of the post data is obfuscated when received. So i'm un obfuscating the post data and writing it to a log file on the server. The contents after obfuscated is a series of random key value pairs that differ between every request. It is not fixed data.

The server is running Linux with 2.6+ kernel. Server is configured to handle heavy traffic (open files limit 32k, etc). The application is written in Python using web.py framework. The http server is Gunicorn behind Nginx.

After using Apache Benchmark to do some load testing, I noticed that it can handle up to about 600-700 requests per second without any log writing issues. Linux natively does a good job at buffering. Problems start to occur when more than this many requests per second attempt to write to the same file at same moment. Data will not get written and information will be lost. I know that "the writing directly to a file" design might not have been the right solution from the get go.

So i'm wondering if anyone can propose a solution that I can implement quickly without altering too much infrastructure and code that can overcome this problem?

I have read about in memory storage like Redis, but I have realized that if data is sitting in memory during server failure then that data is lost. I have read in the docs that redis can be configured as a persistent store, there just needs to be enough memory on the server for Redis to do it. This solution would mean that I would have to write a script that would dump the data from Redis (memory) to the Log file at a certain interval.

I am wondering if there is even a quicker solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: kind of bad design, if you write every request even a request that's considered invalid for some reason , such as missing data/fields/variables or whatever.. you should use some kind of filter or validate the data received, so you can drastically lower the request , then with a queue you could handle file locks and write in an asyncronous way, like whenever the file is available for writing, the first request will be written, and list goes on.

Comment: How are you running gunicorn (which worker class)? If you only have one server process, `logging.FileHandler` could be useful. Otherwise, take a look at `logging.SyslogHandler` as a possible option.

Comment: I have heard that mongodb has very good write performance.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option what I can think of is a separate logging process. So that your web.py can be shielded for performance issue. This is classical way of handling logging module. You can use IPC or any other bus communication infrastructure. With this you will be able to address two issues -

1. Logging will not be a huge bottle neck for high capacity call flows.
2. A separate module can ensure/provide switch off/on facility.
3. As such there would not be any huge/significant process memory usage.

However, you should bear in mind below points -

1. You need be sure that logging is restricted to just logging. It must not be a data store for business processing. Else you may have many synchronization problem in your business logic.
2. The logging process (here I mean actual Unix process) will become critical and slightly complex (i.e you may have to handle a form of IPC).

HTH!

Comment: Pipes will be a good fit since the data flows only in 1 direction.

Comment: Also to add, If you are designing a product from scratch, Suggest to target system capability of atleast 1.5-2 times the expected benchmark. As the product moves through life cycle, the performance would reduce (as and when features are added).